# GoogleAppEngine: dev_appserver crashed

Tags: google-app-engine, jetty, jersey

When  start the development server, Java will crash
What is the cause?

(OS)

```
Mac OS X 10.6.6
```

(Java)

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)
```

(GAE)
    Version 1.4.2

(console)

```
admin$ ./dev_appserver.sh --port=8080 /Users/admin/projects/sample1/war/
2011-03-10 12:51:02.582 java[2542:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2011-03-10 12:51:02.583 java[2542:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
2011/03/10 3:51:03 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
####: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
2011/03/10 3:51:04 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
####: Successfully processed /Users/admin/projects/sample1/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
2011/03/10 3:51:04 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
####: Successfully processed /Users/admin/projects/sample1/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
2011/03/10 3:51:04 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
####: jetty-6.1.x
2011/03/10 3:51:04 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
####: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
sample1.resources
jp.tryden.resources.test
2011/03/10 3:51:04 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
####: Root resource classes found:
class sample1.resources.CheckinsResource
class sample1.resources.UsersResource
class sample1.resources.ItemsResource
2011/03/10 3:51:04 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
####: No provider classes found.
2011/03/10 3:51:05 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl initiate
####: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.1.5.1 03/10/2010 02:33 PM'
2011/03/10 3:51:06 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
####: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8080
2011/03/10 3:51:06 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
####: The server is running at http://localhost:8080/
admin$ ( <- Stopped!! )
```

(crash log)

```
Process:         java [3466]
Path:            /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
Identifier:      java
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  java [3465]

Date/Time:       2011-03-10 14:22:12.206 +0900
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  10  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority

Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             0x000000010301f383 0 + 4345426819
1   ???                             0x000000010300685a 0 + 4345325658
2   ???                             0x0000000103006e8d 0 + 4345327245
3   ???                             0x00000001030069b3 0 + 4345326003
4   ???                             0x00000001030069b3 0 + 4345326003
5   ???                             0x0000000103006e8d 0 + 4345327245
6   ???                             0x000000010300685a 0 + 4345325658
7   ???                             0x000000010300685a 0 + 4345325658
8   ???                             0x000000010300685a 0 + 4345325658
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug introduced in the Apple JDK 10.6 Update 4. Workarounds are discussed in the [appengine group](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712). A developer at Apple has also acknowledged the issue, but I couldn't find a public bug report.

If you have a backup of the previous (Update 3) installation (/Library/Java), restoring that should solve the problem. The previous version of the Apple JDK can be downloaded from http://supportdownload.apple.com/download.info.apple.com/Apple_Support_Area/Apple_Software_Updates/Mac_OS_X/downloads/061-8453.201019.Jva3w/JavaForMacOSX10.6Update3.dmg
You will have to find a way (such as Pacifist) to force it to overwrite the current (more recent) installation.

Answer (score 0):

See here for a full discussion including a detailed resolution:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712

See answer #39.